# 'middle' name as 'None' , where None is expected

Tags: python, sql, cs50

My check50 returns 5 out 6. Having issues with the import.py.

[image: screen shot of issue]

Actual output: returns the 'middle' name as 'None' , where None is expected (without single quotes). I'm really unsure how to fix this. Here is my import.py code...

```
import cs50
import sys
import csv
from cs50 import SQL

db = SQL("sqlite:///students.db")

def get_formatted_name(split_name):
    """Return a formatted name, middle name optional."""
    num_of_names = len(split_name)
    middle_name = None

    if num_of_names == 2:
        full_name = f"{split_name[0]} {middle_name} {split_name[1]}"
    elif num_of_names == 3:
        full_name = f"{split_name[0]} {split_name[1]} {split_name[2]}"
    return full_name


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print(f"Usage: python import.py characters.csv")
    exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)


    for row in reader:
        char_name = row[0]
        split_name = char_name.split()
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name(split_name)

        full_name_list = formatted_name.split()
        first = full_name_list[0]
        middle = full_name_list[1]
        last = full_name_list[2]

        house = row[1]
        birth = row[2]

        db.execute("INSERT INTO students (first, middle, last, house, birth) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            first, middle, last, house, birth)
```

Comment: I feel like there is no enough information to support the problem

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the `None` in a formatted string and splitting the string. Since Python is a duck typed language when you put `None` in a string, it becomes a string, hence the single qoutes around it. Instead of returning the full_name as a formatted string, return it as a dictionary or list from `get_formatted_name()` function.

Here's a little hint:

```
if num_of_names == 2:
    full_name = [split_name[0], middle_name, split_name[1]]
elif num_of_names == 3:
    full_name = [split_name[0], split_name[1], split_name[2]]
```

Then you can just return the full_name and pass that directly to your db.execute.